# implicit conversion during pass by value works, but pass by reference does not

Tags: c++, clang++

Compiling with clang++ 4.1:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const char *s=0) : _s(s) {}
    const char *_s;
};

void f(A a)
{
    cout << a._s << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f("test");
    return 0;
}
```

prints,

```
test
```

whereas if I define `f` as follows,

```
void fA(A &a)
{
    cout << a._s << endl;
}
```

I get a compilation error,

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o test test.cpp
test.cpp:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    f("9000");
    ^
test.cpp:7:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'const char [5]' to 'A &' for 1st argument;
void f(A &a)
     ^
```

Why?  I don't understand why making `f` take a reference leads to problems.

Comment: [Make it a const reference.](http://ideone.com/A52dJY) References cannot bind to temporaries. Only constant references can bind to temporaries.

Comment: Sure it does. Never had any doubts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f("test");` attempts to create a temporary `A` - `f(A("test"));`, but that temporary can't bind to a non-const reference. The pass-by-value is okay because a copy is theoretically made (in practice, copy elision will occur).

Comment: Technically it does not even need to attempt the conversion through `A`, since it knows that it will not get an *lvalue*

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
void f(const A &a)
{
    cout << a._s << endl;
}
```

"test" is temporary object can not be bound to non-const reference